# ansible read parameter value from file

Tags: parameters, ansible

I have a file that looks similarly:

```
# some comment
foo/variable1 = value1
bar/variable2 = value2
```

etc..

I have been trying to come up with an ansible logic to look up one particular variable of interest from this file.
For example if I need to get value2 assigned to myvar in ansible.

tried lineinfile first something like this:

```
- name: taskname
  lineinfile:
    path: /path/to/file
    regexp: '^bar/variable2.*$'
    line: dummy
  register: myvar
  check_mode: yes
```

didn't work. I also tried to escape the / character in the regexp pattern but that wasn't the problem. Then I tried lookup ini file something like:

```
vars: 
  myvar: "{{ lookup('ini', 'bar/variable2 file=/path/to/file') }}"
```

but the file doesn't have sections so this fails too.

I tried using regex_search too in different ways but I just can't seem to have it working. I'd appreciate if somebody can help me. I wish lookup ini file would have a version where the section is optional. There are some parameter files that follow very similar format except they don't have sections in them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ini` lookup seems to work just fine, as long as you have a compatible file format (specifically, you need section headers). For example, if I have a file `data.ini` that contains:

```
[global]
# some comment
foo/variable1 = value1
bar/variable2 = value2
```

Then this works:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ lookup('ini', 'bar/variable2', file='data.ini') }}"
```

Which results in:

```
TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "value2"
}
```

If you don't want to modify your input file, you can do this with regular expressions:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    config: "{{ lookup('file', 'data.ini') }}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: >-
          {{
              config |
              regex_search('^foo/variable1 *= *.*', multiline=True) |
              regex_replace('.*= *(.*)$', '\1')
          }}
```

Which results in:

```
TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "value1"
}
```

---

Some updates in response to your comments:

> What is peculiar about the line breaks that made it working?

Mostly nothing. The line breaks are simply to make it easier to read. You just just as easily write it like this:

```
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ config | regex_search('^foo/variable1 *= *.*', multiline=True) | regex_replace('.*= *(.*)$', '\\1') }}"
```

The only trick here is that inside a double-quoted string, you need to write `\\1` instead of `\1`. If we were to use single quotes on the outside, it would be identical:

```
    - debug:
        msg: '{{ config | regex_search("^foo/variable1 *= *.*", multiline=True) | regex_replace(".*= *(.*)$", "\1") }}'
```

---

> Second, I am trying to understand the regex_replace part.

The output of the `regex_search` is going to be a single line from the config file, something like:

```
foo/variable1 = value1
```

We want just the bit after the `=` sign. The regex replace captures that, and then replaces the entire string with the value of the capture group (`\1`). There may be more optimized ways of doing this, but this is what I came up with off the top of my head.

Comment: Take a look at the update to the question :)

Comment: larsks thank you, this worked. I have a few follow up questions on this though because I would like to understand why it's working :)
I first put the msg command in to one single line and it didn't work. 
msg: "{{ config | regex_search('^foo/variable1 *= *.*', multiline=True) | regex_replace('.*= *(.*)$', '\1')}}"

Then I tried in the exact same format as you wrote here and it did work. What is peculiar about the line breaks that made it working?

Comment: Second, I am trying to understand the regex_replace part. It would search for any number of characters and = + space, and there is a capture the rest of the character until the last character. Then you take the first coloumn captured. But where is the replace here? Couldn't it be a simple regex_search too?

Comment: I've made some updates based on your comments.

Answer (score 0):

There is no ini parser available IMHO. Neither the module [*ini_file*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/modules/ini_file_module.html#ini-file-tweak-settings-in-ini-files) nor the lookup *ini* plugin (see `shell> ansible-doc -t lookup ini`) can read the whole ini file.

But, you can parse it on your own. For example

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        myvars: "{{ myvars|d({})|combine({_key: _val}) }}"
      loop: "{{ lookup('file', 'data.ini').split('\n') }}"
      when: item is match('(?!\s*#).*=.*')
      vars:
        _arr: "{{ item.split('=') }}"
        _key: "{{ _arr.0|trim|regex_replace('[^\\w]', '_') }}"
        _val: "{{ _arr.1|trim }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  myvars:
    bar_variable2: value2
    foo_variable1: value1
```

Notes:

- Potential sections (e.g. [defaults]) will be ignored
- Names of the variables will be fixed. See [Creating valid variable names](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#creating-valid-variable-names).
- If you don't want to change the names of the variables remove the *regex_replace* filter from the expression. The rules of valid Ansible variables' names do not apply to dictionary keys.

Comment: Thank you this is useful if I need to harvest all parameters from a file to ansible variables.

Comment: The lookup *ini* plugin is all you need if you know what variables are in the file and if you want a single variable on-demand only.